# textureAtlas animation gets triggered at start of application

Tags: libgdx, texture-atlas

My problem is that textureAtlas animation runs on start of application. I only want it to be triggered when an inputListner gets the correct input, and not on start. Currently it gets triggered both times. What have missed? this is my code.

```
 //show method 
animationTime=0;

 atlas= new TextureAtlas("Atlas/animation.atlas");
 regions= new Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion>(Atlas.getRegions());
 animation= new Animation(1f/31f,regions);

//input listener:
animationTime = 0;
animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);

//render method:
animationTime+=delta;    
decal.setTextureRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(animationTime));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your animation to be triggered by input you shouldn't call this line all the time :

```
animationTime+=delta;
```

cause this line of code make your animation moved, is suggest this :

```
// render
if(animationTrigger) {
animationTime+=delta; 
}

// input listener
if(input) {
animationTrigger = true;
}
```

The animation will be triggered when the flag is on TRUE

If any trouble leave a comment

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The reason the animation gets triggered at the start of the application is because that's when you started the animation time, if you want it to start at some other point of time, or to just reset it, you can always change the variable or directly pass a float:

```
if(animationContinue) {
    animationTime+=delta; 
}
if(animationReset) {
    animationTime = 0; 
}

// Applying animation using the animation time variable.
decal.setTextureRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(animationTime));

// Will just return the first frame of the animation
decal.setTextureRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(0));
// Note that 1 won't necessarily return the next animation frame
```

As you can see the animation time is completely dynamic and separate from the animation itself.

If you plan to use one animation for multiple game objects, such as birds flying, 
 make sure to add some random offsets to each game object animation time, that will make each of them more unique and more believable.
Otherwise, they all will have the same exact animation timing and sequence, resulting in a really artificial look.

Note that the animation time variable is dynamic and completely separated from the animation itself, therefore, you can just do this:

```
// For each bird.
bird.setTextureRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(animationTime+randomOffset));
```

Will gladly appreciate an upvote, I kinda pushed my effort here :)